# What was the frequency of the gravitational wave recently detected, and why?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, gravitational-waves

In one early Internet post there was a graphic that appeared to show the gravitational wave (pulse) at about 30 cps. And another video it was stated that the gravitational wave would be as high as thousands of cycles per second, corresponding to the rotation rate of the binary pair as it collapsed. Can you resolve this issue and explain why it has its particular frequency?

Answer (score 3):

> On September 14, 2015 at 09:50:45 UTC the two detectors of the Laser Interferometer Gravitational-Wave Observatory simultaneously observed a transient gravitational-wave signal. The signal sweeps upwards in frequency from 35 to 250 Hz with a peak gravitational-wave strain of 1.0×10^−21.

— [Abstract](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.061102) of the article in Physical Review Letters.

The frequency of the gravitational waves we observed would have been, as I understand it, the same as the frequency of the apparent radial motion of the black holes as they spiraled together. Since the system is contracting and angular momentum is conserved, the frequency of the rotation increased with time until the two objects merged. Earlier in time, the frequency would have been lower (indeed much much lower), but because of the lower gravitational stress the signal was also lower, less than we could detect. Apparently it was 30Hz when it reached the threshold of detectability.

[image: Illustration from the article]

Attribution: *Observation of Gravitational Waves from a Binary Black Hole Merger*, B. P. Abbott et al. (LIGO Scientific Collaboration and Virgo Collaboration), DOI: http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.061102, available under CC-BY 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

As the orbiting black holes emit energy in gravitational waves, they move closer to each other and thus orbit faster.  Thus, this binary was orbiting at about 30 revolutions per second near the beginning of when they could detect it.  As the BHs got closer, the orbital speed increased up to about 150 orbits per second when the event horizons touched, and the black holes merged into one larger black hole.